# Issue with word-breakage in JSON code for SharePoint gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint list with gallery view formatted with JSON that is breaking words in half and not wrapping in appropriate places.  I am admittedly a beginner JSON user so I don't always know where to place what but I have tried a number of different placements for "white-space" and "word-wrap" and the closest I can get is to having ALL of the text show but again, it breaks up in weird places.  I also have tried adjusting the width of the card but that distorts the picture.  Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I would greatly appreciate it.

What it looks like:

[image]

Here's my code (also, I don't know what inline code spans are so I apologize for posting the code wrong):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 500,
  "width": 250,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": false,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "img",
                "attributes": {
                  "src": "[$ImageURL]",
                  "title": "My Pet!"
                },
                "style": {
                  "width": "100%",
                  "height": "200px"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "='Hi, my name is: ' + [$Title]"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$PetAge]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$PetAge] == '', '–', 'I am: ' + [$PetAge] + ' years old')"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer",
              "style": {
                "height": "auto"
              }
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "='My nicknames: '+ [$Nicknames]",
                "style": {
                  "white-space": "normal"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer",
              "style": {
                "height": "auto"
              }
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "style": {
                    "white-space": "pre-wrap",
                    "max-height": "80px"
                  }
                },
                "txtContent": "='Fun fact about me: '+ [$FunFact]",
                "style": {
                  "white-space": "normal"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": " "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-label sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "= 'My NCMer is: ' + [$SubmitterDisplayName]"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-label sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "= 'My NCMer works in: ' + [$NCMOffice]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to wrap a text without breaking word you can use [word-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.php) in style.

You should try below JSON code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 500,
  "width": 250,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": false,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "img",
                "attributes": {
                  "src": "[$ImageURL]",
                  "title": "My Pet!"
                },
                "style": {
                  "width": "100%",
                  "height": "200px"
                }
              },
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "='Hi, my name is: ' + [$Title]"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "title": "[$PetAge]",
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "role": "heading",
                  "aria-level": "3"
                },
                "txtContent": "=if ([$PetAge] == '', '–', 'I am: ' + [$PetAge] + ' years old')"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer",
              "style": {
                "height": "auto"
              }
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "='My nicknames: '+ [$Nicknames]",
                "style": {
                  "white-space": "normal"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer",
              "style": {
                "height": "auto"
              }
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent",
                  "style": {
                    "white-space": "pre-wrap",
                    "max-height": "80px"                    
                  }
                },
                "txtContent": "='Fun fact about me: '+ [$FunFact]",
                "style": {
                  "white-space": "normal",
                  "word-break": "break-word"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-content sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": " "
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-label sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "= 'My NCMer is: ' + [$SubmitterDisplayName]"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-displayColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "p",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary sp-card-label sp-card-highlightedContent"
                },
                "txtContent": "= 'My NCMer works in: ' + [$NCMOffice]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See output below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, Kalpesh!  You just solved what I've been banging my head against the wall about for weeks.  THANK YOU!!!!